# Return Oracle constraint exception in BindingResult in Spring MVC/Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application that uses Hibernate 4 to save out to the database (pretty common, I know) haha.

In my Controller, I have my POST method defined as:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,  ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("command") TemplateVO command, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
    ...
    service.addTemplate(command, result);
    ...
}
```

This method takes in the Form Object, populates the Entity and calls the `session.save()` method.

```
@Override
public void addTemplate(TemplateVO form, Errors errors) {
    TemplateEntity template = convert(form);

    save(template, errors);
}
```

Here is the `save()` method:

```
@Override
public void save(Object saveObject, Errors errors) {
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        // Save the object
        session.save(saveObject);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error with Hibernate: ", e);
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }finally {
        try {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }catch(ConstraintViolationException cve) {
            log.error("Oracle constraint violation: ", cve);
            errors.reject("error.someError");

            errors.rejectValue("mainText", 
                          "error.someError", 
                          new Object[]{"test"}, 
                          "Some error occurred");
        }catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            log.error("Error closing session. Session is NULL", npe);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Unknown error thrown when saving:", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The error codes do exist in the messages.properties file.

In Oracle, I have a unique constraint on a field calls GUID. I am testing the application now and trying to put in a GUID with the same name as what already exists. This works fine and the unique constraint is throw and caught in the code above.

I try to populate the `errors` in a couple ways. I tried using `<form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />` but nothing would show, so I tried coming up with my own way by doing this, directly under calling the `addTemplate()`:

```
if (result.hasErrors()) {
    List<ObjectError> errorList = result.getGlobalErrors();
    String errors = "";

    for (FieldError error : errorList) {
        errors += error.getDefaultMessage() + "\n";
    }
    ...
}
```

However, the above always just displayed "null".

So with all that (haha), how can I return an error from the `save()` method and return it all the way back up to the Controller?

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was this:

```
List<ObjectError> errorList = result.getGlobalErrors();
```

It should have been:

```
List<FieldError> errorList = result.getFieldErrors();
```

After switching, I am now getting the error messages